# Why are parentheses added automatically to the join clause when you save a MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures, query-optimization, brackets

When you add or modify a MySQL stored procedure, the code is automatically formatted for consistency. This includes the addition of parentheses to your table joins.

The parentheses appear to force the precedence of joins, to the order they're typed in, rather than allowing the optimiser to select the most performant join ordering based on table statistics.

Is this desirable behaviour? And does it mean that developers should expect SPs to execute differently to standalone select queries?

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW `test` AS
SELECT * 
FROM req
left join stkitm on req.item = stkitm.itm_code
left join itc on stkitm.itm_class = itc.itc_code
```

Now view the code for created view:

```
    SELECT ...*...
    FROM
        ((`req`
        LEFT JOIN `stkitm` ON ((`req`.`item` = `stkitm`.`itm_code`)))
        LEFT JOIN `itc` ON ((`stkitm`.`itm_class` = `itc`.`itc_code`)));
```

Note the opening brackets before the first table name and closing brackets after each join clause.

Comment: These are brackets: `[]`; perhaps you meant parentheses: `()`?

Comment: Thanks Rick, I did indeed mean parentheses rather than brackets. Example coming soon.